# Computing Convergent series, C#

Tags: c#, math

I have an upcoming exam the following question is very likely to come up. I'd really appreciate it if somebody could help me out. Thank you.

Using C# write a procedure to compute the following convergent series to an accuracy of 10^-10.

x^(2n-1) / (2n-1)!

I tried:

```
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        double x, y, numerator, denominator, answer,  e = Math.Pow(10,-10);
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int n = 0;

        do
        {
            numerator = Math.Pow(x, (2 * n - 1));
            denominator = (2 * n - 1);
            answer = (numerator / denominator);
            n++;
        }
        while (answer < e);
   }
}
```

My biggest problem I think, is trying to invoke the factorial function.

Comment: And what problems are you having with the factorial function?  Is it not working, is it to slow, does it not compile, do you not understand it?

Comment: I understand the factorial, what it is and what it does, i just don't know how to use it in programming language

Comment: Have you tried doing a web search?  I'm sure you'll find quite a lot of implementations of a factorial function; it's a rather common academic and practical problem.

Comment: How would you compute a factorial by hand? Whatever steps you do there, replicate in code.

Comment: For example, if i'm trying to find the factorial of n = 20, the formula is : n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*(n-4)*.............*(n-19).  How do I write a loop for this

Comment: @JohnSmith Google for recursive method, that's what factorial is about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a program for convergent series?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302585/writing-a-program-for-convergent-series)

Comment: You already posted this question, about 40 minutes earlier, and it was already closed.  Do NOT repost the exact same question.

Comment: Is `n=0` or `n=1` for the first iteration? For the first case the denominator will be equal to `-1!` which is not defined.

Comment: Notice also that 10^(-10) is `1e-10` in `C#`.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `x^(2n+1) = x^(2n-1) * x^2` and `(2n+1)! = (2n-1)! * 2n * (2n + 1)`. Using this formulas, you can just recalculate your numerator and denominator easily at each iteration of the loop from the previous numerator and denominator, respectively.
The rest is left for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when they say "to an accuracy of 10^-10" it means the answer *changes* by less than that from one pass to another.  Your loop looks good, but you're checking the answer itself, not the change from pass to pass.  Try this change:

```
double lastAnswer = 0.0, delta;   // couple more vars

do
{
    // ... keep current code in loop, add these two lines below

    delta = abs(answer - lastAnswer);   // the change between passes is what's important
    lastAnswer = answer;                // and save last answer for next delta
}
while (delta < e);    // change condition to check difference
```

You might also put in a "sanity check" test on n:

```
while ((delta < e) && (n < 10000000));
```

You can always increase the limit on `n` if your answer isn't close enough.

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is how to do a factorial, this article may help:

http://guyellisrocks.com/algorithms/factorial-function-in-c/

He makes a good point about not needing to re-calculate these values every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const double tol=1e-10;
        double x = 1;
        if(args.Length>0)
        {
            double.TryParse(args[0], out x);
        }
        int n=1;
        const int n_max=100;
        double y=x;

        while(n<n_max && y>tol)
        {
            y=y*x*x/(2*n*(2*n+1));
            n++;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format( "x={0:R}, y={1:R}, n={2}", x, y, n));
    }
}
```

Why? Well this is the part you can figure out on your own.